# How to load Data in UITableView Cell from an Api in swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am Doing this code. How to solve this problem after this code.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

class SymptomFieldsName {

var name: String?
var slug: String?
var msp_enabled: Bool?
var results: Array<String>?


required init(json: JSON, id: Int?) {

    self.name = json[RecordFields.Name.rawValue].stringValue
    self.slug = json[RecordFields.Slug.rawValue].stringValue
    self.msp_enabled = json[RecordFields.Mspenabled.rawValue].boolValue

    if let jsonArray = json[RecordFields.Results.rawValue].array
    {

        self.results = Array<String>()
        for entry in jsonArray {
            self.results?.append(entry.stringValue)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Endpoints
func endpointForSpecies() -> String 
{
    return "http://52.74.163.60/api/symptoms_list/"
}

func getSpeciesAtPath( path: String, completionHandler: (SymptomName?, NSError?) -> Void)  {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, path)
        .responseSpeciesArray { (request, response, symptomName, error) in
            if let anError = error
            {
                completionHandler(nil, error)
                return
            }
            completionHandler(symptomName, nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code for UITableViewCell?

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
       
        
       
 
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        
    }

Comment: I want to fetch data in UITableView from Api in swift. so plg require code

Answer (score 1):

Use  NSJSONSerialization

```
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: <# JSON file URL #>)

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {

(data, response, error) -> Void in

if error == nil{
    jsonArray = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves) as! [NSDictionary]

   // That way the entire JSON file is stored in an array of Dictionaries which can be accessed with key : value pairs

        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following detail explaination:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

class SymptomFieldsName {

 let path = "http://52.74.163.60/api/symptoms_list/"
  var ArrayOfString : [String] = []  // array of String data type.
  @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!      

  func getSpeciesAtPath( path: String) -> Void)  {

 //Step 2: Alamofire request call.
    Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.request(.GET, path, parameters: nil,  encoding: .JSON).responseJSON()
            {
                (request, responce, result) in

                if(result.isSuccess)
                {

                    //Step 3: We have used Swifty JSON to convert result into json array.
                    let json1 = JSON(result.value!) 

                   self.ArrayOfString = json1["stringvalue"].stringValue


                 }
          } //Alamofire ends here
     }//Function ends here


 //MARK: UITableViewDataSource Function

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
      return ArrayOfString.count
    }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

       print(indexPath.row) // Here you will get elements in `ArrayOfString` array
       return cell
    }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     print(indexPath) // This will return selected row index.
    }





 }//Class ends here
```

`ArrayOfString` contains your resultant string values.
Hope this detail explanation will work for you.